# How to save DeferredDataFrame to feather with DataflowRunner?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to compute a [sentence-transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) model for various rows stored in BigQuery, and then store them in a `feather` dataframe in Google Cloud Storage.

However, I'm having problems in saving the actual dataframe. I'm not able to save it locally or in Google Cloud Storage, but get no error.

Here's a reproducible example I've come up with:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.ml.inference.base import (
    ModelHandler,
    PredictionResult,
    RunInference,
)
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import argparse
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from typing import Sequence, Optional, Any, Dict, Iterable
from apache_beam.ml.inference.base import KeyedModelHandler
from apache_beam.dataframe.convert import to_dataframe

ENCODING_MODEL_NAME = "distiluse-base-multilingual-cased-v1"


class EmbeddingModelHandler(
    ModelHandler[str, PredictionResult, SentenceTransformer]
):
    def __init__(self, model_name: str = ENCODING_MODEL_NAME):
        self._model_name = model_name

    def load_model(self) -> SentenceTransformer:
        from sentence_transformers import (
            SentenceTransformer,
        )  # <- These imports are needed otherwise GCP complains
        import sentence_transformers

        return sentence_transformers.SentenceTransformer(self._model_name)

    def run_inference(
        self,
        batch: Sequence[str],
        model: SentenceTransformer,
        inference_args: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
    ) -> Iterable[PredictionResult]:
        from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
        import sentence_transformers

        embedding_matrix = model.encode(
            batch, show_progress_bar=True, normalize_embeddings=True
        )

        return embedding_matrix


class GetFeatures(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        feature = element.get("overview", "")
        iid = element.get("iid")
        return [(iid, feature)]


def run(argv=None):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output",
        dest="output",
        required=True,
        help="Output file to write results to.",
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:

        embedding_dataframe = (
            pipeline
            | "Read BigQuery"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query="""SELECT text_to_embed,
                                identifier
                                FROM  [gcp-project:gcp-dataset.gcp-table]
                                LIMIT 20
                                """,
                project="gcp-project",
                gcs_location="gs://ml-apache-beam/tmp/",
            )
            | "Get features" >> beam.ParDo(GetFeatures())
            | "Run inference"
            >> RunInference(
                KeyedModelHandler(EmbeddingModelHandler(ENCODING_MODEL_NAME))
            )
            | "To Rows"
            >> beam.Map(
                lambda element: __import__("beam").Row(
                    biggint=int(element[0]), embedding=element[1].tolist()
                )
            )
        )

    df = to_dataframe(embedding_dataframe)
    df.to_feather(known_args.output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

And my `requirements.txt`:

```
sentence-transformers==2.2.2
```

With python 3.8.14

To run it locally, I use:

```bash
python beam_pipeline.py   --requirements_file requirements.txt  --output embedding_output.feather
```

Which runs fine, but I see no `embedding_output.feather` in the directory.

And to run it on GCP:

```bash
python beam_pipeline.py   --requirements_file requirements.txt  --output "gs://my-bucket/embedding_output.feather" --runner DataflowRunner --project my-gcp-project --region us-central1
```

Also runs fine, but the `gs://my-bucket/embedding_output.feather` file is not there as well.

Comment: Can you provide the error messages you are getting?

Comment: In your code block, the `to_dataframe` and `to_feather` calls are outside of the `with beam.Pipeline ..` context. Once that context is exited, Beam runs the pipeline. So you are applying them _after_ the pipeline has run. Can you try running with those calls inside the Pipeline context?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT there was no error message. That was the problem.

Comment: @TheNeuralBit, you are right! I put those calls in the with block and it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@TheNeuralBit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2952954/theneuralbit) for the help here!

The problem is that this part of the code:

```py
    df = to_dataframe(embedding_dataframe)
    df.to_feather(known_args.output)
```

Was outside of the pipeline block:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
```

I indented the `to_dataframe` part and it all worked great:

```py
# ... 
def run(argv=None):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output",
        dest="output",
        required=True,
        help="Output file to write results to.",
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:

        embedding_dataframe = (
            pipeline
            | "Read BigQuery"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query="""SELECT text_to_embed,
                                identifier
                                FROM  [gcp-project:gcp-dataset.gcp-table]
                                LIMIT 20
                                """,
                project="gcp-project",
                gcs_location="gs://ml-apache-beam/tmp/",
            )
            | "Get features" >> beam.ParDo(GetFeatures())
            | "Run inference"
            >> RunInference(
                KeyedModelHandler(EmbeddingModelHandler(ENCODING_MODEL_NAME))
            )
            | "To Rows"
            >> beam.Map(
                lambda element: __import__("beam").Row(
                    biggint=int(element[0]), embedding=element[1].tolist()
                )
            )
        )

        df = to_dataframe(embedding_dataframe)
        df.to_feather(known_args.output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```